# Is there a guide to which Blu-ray media can be burned by manufacturers?

Tags: compatibility, burning, optical-drive, blu-ray

Is there a guide to which Blu-ray media can be burned by manufacturers?

For example, can you advise me which computer drives (internal and/or external) can record on this media: Japanese import blank Verbatim BD XL 100Gb 2-4x discs:

- bought on Amazon marketplace.  the part number is VBR520YP5V1.
- Mitsubishi Kagaku Media/Verbatim. the packaging is largely Japanese

What I have researched so far:

- the media does not work with my Pioneer BDR-XD04T - only TDK 100Gb BD XL is listed which I am a little surprised to discover as I considered Verbatim to be a premium quality brand. Indeed, in my work at Philips Semiconductors (now NXP) developing optical drive firmware,  Verbatim as among the brands we used as reference for testing.
- Although I have a Pioneer BDR-XD04T, I am willing to purchase another drive that will record on this Verbatim 100Gb BD-R XL media, as I am upgrading a PC and would purchase a drive as part of this upgrade. So internal or external drives equally fine.
- I have translated into English http://www.verbatim.jp/support/recorder_bdrxl.html but this appears to be for set-top blu-ray recorders, not PC-based.
- I have researched some downloadable manuals for other drive models but not found complete information regarding compatibility: some manufacturers don't seem to mention it in their documentation, but I did find that Samsung have mentioned it in one of their models - that this particular media from Verbatim is not compatible with that model.
- I have generally searched on google but not found anything definitive yet.
- I have been on Verbatim Europe but could not find anything there.
- There must be one or more drives that can burn on this media as otherwise Verbatim could not sell it.

Thanks for your help.